# Reading raw POST/XML data from 3rd party application

Tags: php, xml, post

I am beginning a project with a 3rd party application that is supposed to be POSTing XML data to a URL that I provide when a certain action is completed. I also have the option in the 3rd party application of having it send the XML via email as well as POSTing to the URL I specify.

I am receiving the XML email so I am certain that that works, but I am not entirely sure how I can tell when I receive the POST/XML data.

The script that I wrote to test is the following.

I've read lots of questions here and read through the PHP documentation, but as I'm still a beginner, I'm not sure if this is right.

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($_POST);
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($xml);
var_dump($xml);
```

So what I am doing is performing the action that triggers the 3rd party application to send the data, and then right after, I try running the PHP script to see if there's anything printed to my screen -- it's just that the `print_r()` and `var_dump()` of `$_POST` and `$xml` are empty.

In theory is this how I would go about echoing out the data, simply as a first step to verify that I'm receiving it?

If not, what can I do as a first step just to see that I'm receiving it?

Answer (score 0):

If the 3rd party app is sending you a file, you have to fetch it with `$_FILES`, save it with `move_uploaded_file()` and then read it with `fopen()`

Comment: I had not thought that perhaps the application was POSTing a file to the URL I provide, as I do not have any documentation yet.  I will give that a shot and check back in.  Thank you!